# Cannot read property 'getTranslation' of undefined

Tags: ionic-framework, ngx-translate

I'm developing Ecommerce app using ionic-3. The app is in multiple language and i have used ngx-translate for translate language but I'm getting error of translate. I have enclosed error image below. Let me know if you know any solution.
Thank you.

[image: a]

Comment: It happens the same to me running a unit test with ngx-translate-core 13 and angular 11. TranslateService seems to be undefined while running the test. Explicitly setting it in providers (should be already provided by TranslateModule.forRoot) does not help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';


  constructor(
    private translate: TranslateService,
  ) {
    // console.log(translate.translations);
    translate.getTranslation('en').subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```